# Cannot use data of .csv File

Tags: powershell, csv, import-from-excel

I want to import a CSV file and parse it. But when I try to declare a variable with data, I get nothing back.

```
$file = "H:\Srv-kt01-mgt\Names.csv"
$data = Import-Csv $file 

foreach ($item in $data ) {
    $surname = $($item.nachname)
    $name = $($item.vorname)

    Write-Host "Last Name: $surname"
    Write-Host "First Name: $name" 
}
```

[[image: PowerShell detects the File and the Header]

Can somebody explain why this doesn't work?

Comment: Do you use the correct delimiter? Try -Delimiter ";"

Comment: The default delimiter is the comma. If you use another one you will have to provide it. `$data = import-csv $file -Delimiter ';'`